# c# validate that string contains matching number of brackets

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq, validation

If I have a string like this...

```
"123[1-5]553[4-52]63244[19-44]"
```

...what's the best way to validate the following conditions:

1. Every open bracket has a matching close bracket
2. There are no more than **3** sets of brackets
3. There are **no** nested brackets (i.e., [123-[4]9])

Would a regex be able to validate all of these scenarios?  If not, how about LINQ?

Comment: I would think regex would work and return you all matches enclosed by `[...]`. If I were better with regex I'd give you something to work with. ;)

Comment: @mbeckish the linked question does address #1 above but not #2 or #3 so I don't think it's an exact duplicate.  I want to disallow nested brackets whereas the linked question specifically includes them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you don't allow nesting, you can use a regex:

```
^([^[\]]*\[[^[\]]*\]){0,3}[^[\]]*$
```

Explanation:

- `(...){0,3}` matches up to three sets of the following:

  - `[^[\]]*` matches optional non-bracket characters
  - `\[` matches  `[` to open a group
  - `[^[\]]*` matches optional non-bracket characters inside the group
  - `\]` matches `]` to close the group
- Finally, `[^[\]]*` matches more optional non-bracket characters after all of the groups

Comment: It doesn't seem to be valid when I test with regexhero (.NET tester). The first number in the repetition is necessary.

Comment: @SLaks thank you very much for the regex but more importantly, for a great explanation of it.

Comment: Only problem, this will also match `123[1-5]553[]63244[1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa4]`

Comment: @Jason: That ought to be valid.  (to put it differently, regexes are better at expressing his requirements than the question is)

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to do this would be just to iterate the string

```
bool Validate(string input) 
{
    int braceBalance = 0;
    int openCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == '[') 
        {
            braceBalance++;
            openCount++;
        }
        if (openCount > 3) return false;  // More than 3 pairs
        if (input[i] == ']') braceBalance--;
        // Check for nesting:
        if (braceBalance < -1 || braceBalance > 1) return false;
    }
    return (braceBalance == 0); // Check for equal number of opening and closing
}
```

RegEx and Linq will both have greater overhead than this (although depending on your application, that may not matter).

Comment: thanks for the great answer!  I don't need to validate this kind of data very often and the strings are relatively short so the added overhead of the regex is acceptable for my purposes.

Comment: That's often the case, and RegEx is quite useful in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Just to see if it would be plausible, here is a LINQ:y solution:

```
bool[] b =
  input.Where(c => c == '[' || c == ']')
  .Select((c,i) => (c == '[') == (i % 2 == 0))
  .ToArray();

bool valid = b.Length % 2 == 0 && b.Length <= 6 && b.All(i => i);
```

It filters out the `[` and `]` characters, then checks that there are only alternating brackets (starting with `[`), an even number, and not more than 6 of them.