# Parsing a string to extract a command and associated parameters with nested brackets

Tags: c#, string, parsing, nested

I have a string that contains nested brackets:

```
string commandLine = "position(1, random(1, random(1, 9)), random(3, 15))"
```

I would like to interpret this string with the following rules

*CommandName(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3)*

Where:

- '(' and ')' brackets denote the parameters associated with the command name
- ',' comma separates each parameter

This leads me to believe that I would first need to devise a method to determine the correct opening and closing brackets associated with each command.

It seems from the top answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032770/c-sharp-validate-that-string-contains-matching-number-of-brackets) question that I can't use Regex. How then should I approach this task?

EDIT:

Had a thought.

Count the number of '(' brackets after hitting the first opening bracket.
That number indicates the index of the closing bracket bracket in the subsequent collection of ')'

My wording fails me but I believe that's a start?

```
position(1, random(1, random(1, 9)), random(3, 15))

Opening 1         2         3              4
Closing                          12              34
```

Comment: And some miserable user has down voted without any constructive criticism.  Thanks.

Comment: For your own sake, don't go calling anyone miserable, this will only alienate someone who is willing to help you, better ask why the question was downvoted.

Comment: I understand your point but the adjective only applies to the person who gave the down vote.  It was not directed at anyone willing to give an answer.  Would it not be best to make a comment first then down vote rather than leaving the asker bemused?

Comment: @user1423893: It would be best, but it's not *required*. Calling people miserable without justification (and really, it's just a downvote -- they didn't e.g. show pleasure in harassing you) is neither civil nor helpful to you.

Comment: The miserable comment was tongue in cheek and their pleasure had not crossed my mind so I'm not sure where you got that from. Point taken though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go about this a lot of ways. Here is one:

Match all occurrences of `[a-z]+\s*\([^()]+\)` using a regular expression. This will only match commands whose parameters do not include any other commands. In your example, these would be `random(1, 9)` and `random(3, 15)`.

For each of the matches, calculate the result (or produce an in-memory representation, whatever your thing is). This should not be difficult, as you can easily isolate the command name and split on commas to separate the parameters (there is no chance of misparsing here, since we know no parameter is a command).

Store the result in a dictionary using something that is not ambiguous as a key. For example, assuming that it is normally illegal for a parameter to start with `?`, after the first step you could end up with this dictionary:

```
"?1" => [the result or representation of random(1, 9)]
"?2" => [the result or representation of random(3, 15)]
```

Replace the original matches with the placeholders `?1` and `?2`. You have now eliminated the innermost nested commands. Repeat the procedure, referring to the dictionary as required; each iteration will eliminate the set of innermost commands.

When the input string (after being the subject of several transformations) has been reduced to the form `?XXX` you have parsed everything successfully and the final result is the last entry added to the dictionary (you can just pull it out using the input string as a key). If the regular expression does not match anything and the input string is not in this form, the original input had a syntax error.

This is not the most efficient algorithm by far, but it's easy to implement at a high level and doesn't require you to write tedious char-by-char parsing code.